# Can't boot Windows without connecting external device that has Ubuntu installed on it

Tags: boot, system

I made a Ubuntu bootable USB, let's call it USB A.

I used this USB A to boot Ubuntu and install Ubuntu (with third party software) in my external hardware device (let's call it USB B)

My notebook already had Windows 7 installed. After installing Ubuntu I turned on my notebook and I saw a message: `error: can't find device: eeeeeee grub repair?`. I was very surprised and I searched for a method to solve this.

I booted live Ubuntu with USB A and used the GRUB restore program to restore GRUB.

Now, using I use USB B I can boot Windows 7. But I still want to be able to boot Windows without using USB B.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like  GRUB is installed on USB B - so your system will only boot, even into Windows, when USB B is connected. When USB B is disconnected the boot loader can't find GRUB and fails.

You can run boot repair and make sure that GRUB is installed on your internal hard disk - e.g. sda

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair